A word for something that is, "Bizarre" but, "Beautiful"
Is there a word that describes something that is weird, strange, odd, bizarre, etc. but also beautiful, wonderful, amazing, fantastic, etc.?
Example: a word to describe a place that is strangely lovely, welcoming, and peaceful despite it being absurd and ridiculous looking/feeling.
I found the word, "Selcouth", but I don't think that word would be a good fit for what I need. Basically, I'm looking for synonyms of Selcouth (if there are any) but not necessarily just synonyms of Selcouth. I also don't want to use general, everyday words like weird or wonderful, etc.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The word fantastical might fit. Cambridge defines one sense of it as:

strange and wonderful, like something out of a story


I think fantastic[al] is the closest you can get with a single word. While not outright bizarre, it's still fanciful, and also carries a positive vibe, even though it does not get all the way to "beautiful".

I would use wondrous here:

If you describe something as wondrous, you mean it is strange and beautiful or impressive.
[literary]

We were driven across this wondrous vast land of lakes and forests. (Collins)


Vocabulary.com has a usage note that sheds more light on its meaning:

The adjective wondrous is a great word to use when you're describing something amazing or delightful. You could talk about the wondrous view of the ocean from the cliffs where you're standing.
There's a hint of magic and awe about the word wondrous. It describes things that inspire wonder, like a wondrous imaginary land or a wondrous display of beautiful, elaborate cakes at a pastry shop. The root is the Old English wundor, "marvelous thing, or object of astonishment."


"And at night the wondrous glory of the everlasting stars."

A display of beautiful cakes e.g. may be wonderful (wondrous), but how is it weird, strange, or bizarre?

I wouldn't describe a display of cake as wondrous, I must say...

or the compound phrase, "wondrous strange"

@fev Mine would be more likely to be labelled bizarre.

@EdwinAshworth Without false modesty, I would call mine maybe promising, but definitely not wondrous...

The word with a large overlap between the two different senses required is (as proposed by Xanne) exotic:

exotic [adjective]

having a strange or bizarre allure, beauty, or quality

    2'. strange or different in a way that is
striking or fascinating; strangely beautiful, enticing, etc.

[Webster’s New World College Dictionary, 4th Edition; selective]
It is, however, polysemous (having other senses).

striking : attracting attention by reason of being unusual, extreme, or prominent. dramatically good-looking or beautiful. +1. ... (exotic : originating in or characteristic of a distant foreign country) -1. ... (Oxford Languages)

For beautiful and strange, you might try a word with both of these definitions (though one of them is considered obsolete or dialectical):

curious adjective & adverb
II.14. † Without explicit reference to workmanship: Exquisite, choice, excellent, fine (in beauty, flavour, or other good quality).
Obsolete or dialect. (Cf. modern use of nice.) c1475–1816 [selected attestations] 1665   A very
calme curious morning. —S. Pepys, Diary 24 September (1972) vol. VI.
240 1725   In about thirty or forty Days it
will be curious Vinegar. —R. Bradley, Chomel's Dictionaire Œconomique
at Vinegar
II.16.a. Deserving or exciting attention on account of its novelty or peculiarity; exciting curiosity; somewhat surprising, strange,
singular, odd; queer. (The ordinary current objective sense.)
1715– [selected attestations] 1719   What is Rare, and Curious without any Other consideration we
Naturally take Pleasure in. —J. Richardson, Sci. Connoisseur
204 1868   Seated in the piazza..I had before
me a curious scene. —C. W. Dilke, Greater Britain vol. II. iv.
163
Source: Oxford English Dictionary (login
required)

So, for example:

Curious Worlds of the Universe


Curious is the go-to word in Lovecraft's work.

In the US they would say "far out".  It has both the connotation of oddness and that of being appreciated.

Maybe 30 years ago... that phrase is not so common in the US anymore. FWIW, it means something closer to "that's weird and I love it" than "that's weird and beautiful."

"Quaint" is where my mind goes, it is defined as 'attractively unusual or old-fashioned' which captures what you want.

Not exactly synonymous with 'fantastical', but still a valid response.

But this word almost always means old fashioned. I don't think OP has mentioned old fashioned anywhere in the question.

Old fashioned things are often beautiful and bizarre, so for that reason I'd say it is still valid.

I would use two words to convey the negative and the positive
like strangely intoxicating, something like that, or oddly wonderous.

-1 – wonderous has already been suggested. As for "strangely intoxicating" you might as well say "strangely/oddly beautiful" both of which work very well.

I think the word you are looking for is simply stunning.
This word can be used in place for all of the words you have in your question but moreover it is one of the "ultimate" words for both beautiful and bizarre.

For me, this use of "stunning" implies that the thing in question is exceptionally beautiful, but not in an unconventional/bizarre way.

@JakeRobb - wouldn't an alien spaceship landing in your back yard be a stunning event?

It probably would! But that'd be the first definition here, whereas we're talking about the second definition in this question. (Depending on what the ship looks like, it could potentially be both.)
